# Is it possible to return few vars with __toString magic method?

Tags: php, class

I have a class with 4 vars and I want to print them separately as strings. (print each of them in different places).

this is apart of the class: (as you can see I use the __tostring method to return only one of the vars but I want to use it for all of them.)

```
class dash
{
public $name;
public $msg;
public $msg_date;
public $votes;

function __construct($name,$msg,$msg_date,$votes){
$this->name=$name;
$this->msg=$msg;
$this->msg_date=$msg_date;
$this->votes=$votes;}

public function __toString(){
return $this->name;
}
```

I have to print it here:

```
function repliesView(){
$arr=objectsToArr();
$count=count($arr)-1;
for($i=0;$i<=$count;$count--){
echo "<p>name:$arr[$count]->name<br />"; 
echo "msg:$arr[$count]->msg<br />";
echo "date:arr[$count]->msg_date</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably write a function that does this but don't use `__toString`. `__toString` is a special function, you shouldn't really use it to do anything application critical. Use it for debugging and inspecting.

---

```
function toHTML() {
    return "<p>" . htmlentities($this->name) . "<br />"
      . "msg: " . htmlentities($this->msg) . "<br />"
      . "date: " . htmlentities($this->msg_date) . "</p>";
}
```

Then:

```
function repliesView() {
    $arr = objectsToArr();
    $count = count($arr)-1;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $count--) {
        echo $arr[$count]->toHTML();
    }
}
```

Comment: So how can I print Object methods as a string? I have to print them with html statements in a php function.

Comment: Your properties are public so you could just access then right away. Could you elaborate on your use case?

Answer (score 1):

`__toString` is supposed to represent the whole object as a string.

As far as [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) is concerned, you should simply have a get method for each field so you can easily retrieve them. Eventually you can use `__toString` to retrieve the most common field, in order to spare some code (still not a very good practice).

Comment: I added my case please watch it.

Comment: ok, then you can either keep using `echo "<p>name:".$arr[$count]->name."<br />";` or implement a getter method `public function getName(){return $this->name;}` and call it like this: `echo "<p>name:".$arr[$count]->getName()."<br />";`.

Answer (score 0):

The `__toString()` method will not be of much help here, but you could always do something like:

```
class dash
{
    public $name;
    public $msg;
    public $msg_date;
    public $votes;
    function __construct($name, $msg, $msg_date, $votes) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->msg = $msg;
        $this->msg_date = $msg_date;
        $this->votes = $votes;
    }
    public function getName() {
        return($this->name);
    }
    public function getMsg() {
        return($this->msg);
    }
    public function getMsgDate() {
        return($this->msg_date);
    }
    public function getVotes() {
        return($this->votes);
    }
}
```

Then call the methods after you initialize the class:

```
$dash = new dash("John Doe", "Message text", "12/4/13", 4);
echo($dash->getName());
// Which would return John Doe
```

Comment: I added my case to the topic...please watch it.

Comment: the problem is how can I add html to this?

Comment: Add it into the `echo` when you call the method or the `return` within the method. Either one will do the trick.

Comment: What I meant is how can I involve html with it? when I call echo "<p>$dash->getName()</p>;   it gives an error that I print object as string. the problem solved but can give an example please?

Comment: You have to escape the method call, something like: `"<p>" . $dash->getName() . "</p>"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing up what `__toString()` does. `__toString()` gets executed when you try using the object as a string.

Eg:

```
class Dash {
    public function __tostring() { return 'Hello'; }
}

$obj = new Dash();
echo (string) $obj;

>> Hello
```

If you want to be able to access the private/protected member variables in your object, use `__get()`.

Eg:

```
class Dash {
    protected $var1, $var2;
    public function __get($k) { 
        if ($k === 'var1' || $k === 'var2') {
            return (string) $this->$k; 
        }
    }
}

$obj = new Dash();
echo $obj->var1;
echo $obj->var2;
```